Determining biological replicates with pooled samples
Our group has had a long-standing protocol wherein multiple tissue purifications are pooled. This is because there is very little of the tissue per animal. This pool was then sampled several times and an outcome of interest measured. Each measurement was treated as an independent data point for inferential analysis. While these individual samples might be "replicates", their status as biological replicates is highly questionable, at best. They look like they might be pseudoreplicates.
I.e., Animals were treated with two drugs. Extracted tissues were combined into two pools. Each pool is sampled x times. These samples were then analyzed by drug treatment with n = x for each treatment.
How ought this design be adjusted? No means currently exists to use tissue from just one animal for the assay. Tissues must be combined.
If we use more animals and created several pools, then each pool could be sampled several times to account for variation introduced by combining animals. This would be modeled with a mixed-level model. Would each pool would be a single biological replicate, and each sample from a pool be a cluster within a random effect?
So, two treatments, M animals per treatment. Tissue extractions combined into P pools, and each pool sampled N times. Model with n = P per treatment and the individual sample clustered by P.
Is there another way to do this?
(This is a re-casting of a question I had asked recently, but it was poorly worded and confusing.

You are correct that this is pseudoreplicated. If you are combining the tissue from all individuals in one treatment into one pool, then you don't have any basis for any meaningful statistical analysis, unfortunately. It's effectively a 1 vs. 1 comparison.
If no basis exists for analysing the tissue from one individual, the only reasonable alternative is the one you suggest: using many more individuals in the experiment and creating multiple pools, each with a distinct set of individuals.
If you sample once from each pool, then a simple linear regression/ANOVA would do. Note however that your degrees of freedom is determined by the number of pools, not the number of individuals that went into them.
If you sample from each pool multiple times, you will need to account for the non-independence, which is commonly done with a mixed/hierarchical model. Note that this isn't really done to account for 'variation introduced by combining animals', because you would model this the same way even if each pool here was a single individual and you therefore had multiple measurements per individual. It's simply to account for the fact that samples from the same pool are more similar to each other than they are to samples from other pools.

The biochemist in me suggests that the OP and colleagues should concentrate on scaling down the extraction procedure to handle single tissue samples, as you imply. In a world where we can now quantify thousands of nucleic acids and proteins in individual mammalian cells, that should be possible. (+1)

And the years of funding for that scaling down methods research would come from where? It is far easier to quantify nucleic acids than to measure transportation across a capillary membrane rather than an artificial proxy.
